# Is CSS faster when you are specific?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Is **div.container** faster than **.container** ? 
You know like in jquery if you be more specific with your selectors it is faster since it iterates through less.. Is this the case with css ?

Is there a way to measure performance in css ?
Performance wise, does things like this even matter or does it all depend on text weight basically ?

I'd be happy if someone knows the answer to it, I've actually found a similar question with no certain answer.
[Can CSS be more efficient if it is better specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697706/can-css-be-more-efficient-if-it-is-better-specified)

Comment: I'd say `.container` is faster than `div.container` because it uses a lower number of bytes (so the css is transferred faster). When it comes to the browser rendering the content though, I don't know.

Comment: This is implementation dependent.

Comment: I can't back this up, but I strongly believe it's irrelevant. Every browser's render cycle queries every element against every style rules to match

Comment: And please, define "faster". The difference must be of less than milliseconds, does it really matter? What may make the CSS rendering slower is the properties you set to the rules, not to the selector itself.

Comment: If both selectors match same elements then `div.container` should be slower since it (a) matches all `.container` elements (b) filters out `div` elements.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In real world the speed difference would be negligible.
To be technical `.container` would be faster as it has fewer selectors to process.

Selectors have an inherent efficiency.  The order of more to less efficient CSS selectors goes thus:

1. ID, *e.g. `#header`*
2. Class, *e.g. `.promo`*
3. Type, *e.g. `div`*
4. Adjacent sibling, *e.g. `h2 + p`*
5. Child, *e.g. `li > ul`*
6. Descendant, *e.g. `ul a*`
7. Universal, *i.e. `*`*
8. Attribute, *e.g. `[type="text"]`*
9. Pseudo-classes/-elements, *e.g. `a:hover`*

In regards to your second question:

> Is there a way to measure performance in CSS ?

Steve Souders put out an online test to measure performance of CSS that can still be accessed [here](http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php).

There are better ways to measure performance nowadays, but this is a quick and easy resource you can play with.

> Performance wise, does things like this even matter or does it all depend on text weight basically ?

The short answer is "not really".

The long answer is, "it depends".  If you are working on a simple site there is really no point to make a fuss about CSS performance other than general knowledge you may gain from best practices.

If you are creating a site with tens of thousands of DOM elements then yes, it will matter.

Comment: I've read further and further and still dont have an exact answer in mind. I used to think being specific was better but it seems that it works the other way around for CSS, the more specific you be, the worse it gets since it traverses the whole DOM tree every time.
So, I guess I will try to keep my rules as general as possible.

Comment: The name you listed is "Steve Sounders" but the url has "Steve Souders" - is that a typo?

Comment: If you want to test CSS performance, you can also resize the window. If it shows no content, then the CSS is too heavy.

Comment: @ChrisHayes - No, that is intentional.  Steve Sounder's is a person and his domain name is his name.

Comment: @xengravity: but you spell his surname with an "n" in it, and his domain spells it without one. This is why Chris thinks one of the two is probably in error :-)

Comment: The part about "inherent efficiency" as well as the order of selectors is plagiarized from Steve Souders' book (as well as http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/ which quotes it online). But if we're going to talk about "inherent efficiency", I find it really hard to believe that the universal selector would rank that low, considering that it's a guaranteed match for any non-featureless element. But I'm not Steve Souders...

Comment: Thanks for this list, I thought that type selectors would've been faster than class selectors though.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the fewer the rules the better, so .container would be faster than div.container.  Apart from caching, the .container gets read first, then other elements have to have the div added on as a second-level filter... unnecessary in many circumstances.

This is pretty common across engine, though there are some minor deltas.

See this article:  [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS?redirect=no), which although it is from MDN (and is therefore Mozilla-geared) holds true for most of what I know about the engines in general.

Comment: I would advise against the mantra that "fewer rules are better". 

* is infinitely worse than say: html > body > div > .container

On the other hand the idea that "more specific rules are better" is certainly true.

Comment: You bring up an interesting point, but I believe that * should actually be faster than html>body>div>.container.  What * does is insert itself above the the default browser stylesheet for all tags.  Since CSS is basically a sandwich model, that just makes it a lower level (and therefore less specific) selector, but one that trumps default style.  It isn't as if you're going to do a memcopy into each object (like you would through jquery or something).  So although there are elements of what you say that may be correct, suggesting that * is inherently slower than running 5 rules is debatable.

Comment: @JohnGreen so why need css Combinator? why not use specific class name like "UserdivContainerLinke" instead of ".User .Container>a" ??

Answer (score 4):

> delta between the best case and the worst case was 50ms. In other words, consider selector performance but don’t waste too much time on it.
>   See: https://smacss.com/book/selectors

So I do not think it makes much sense to extend CSS rules ONLY to get a higher performance. Just consider the higher amount of network traffic, maybe worse maintainability, ...
However in the link you can read, which rules to consider without having to increase the CSS size.

If .container and div.container match exactly the same elements on your page, the first one might be even faster: If the browser evaluates .container at first, actually it would have been finished, but with div.container it has ADDITIONALLY to check, whether the element is a div.

disclaimer: I do not know how browsers really implement these things. My conclusions are based on the linked article.